# Make ASP.NET Identity 2.0 Email confirm token work for WCF and MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I have a service project (WCF) and MVC project which uses same database, to handle service part for Mobile and Interface part. I have to set up email confirmation on both.

I have used OWIN ASP.NET 2.0 library for authentication, and both projects have separate UserManagers.

For MVC

```
public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
{
  var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
  if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
  {
    manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET"));
  }
}
```

For WCF

```
var provider = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection.DpapiDataProtectionProvider("ASP.NET");
UserManager.UserTokenProvider =new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(
provider.Create("EmailConfirm"));
var code = idManager.UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(appuser.Id);
```

**The Problem**
The email confirmation token generated in MVC works fine.

In WCF when i create an email confirmation token, it needs to be verified from MVC website.
Here it gives me "Invalid Token".

I think it is due to the Token Codes not matching, I tried to make them same as i can, but don't really know which one goes where between Wcf and MVC.

btw. I am testing on localhost from Visual studio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was the `DataProtectionProvider`.

On **MVC**, it was getting from:

```
public static ApplicationUserManager    
    Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
      var dataProtectionProvider = **options.DataProtectionProvider**;
```

On **WCF**, it was from:

```
var provider = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection.DpapiDataProtectionProvider("ASP.NET");
```

So I used same as WCF in MVC:

```
var dataProtectionProvider = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection.DpapiDataProtectionProvider("ASP.NET");
```

Also, the key point is:

- **Provider name**. It should be the same on both.
- While creating the URL from WCF, we need to use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` to **encode the token code**.

Example:

```
var code = UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(appuser.Id);    
var callbackUrl = string.Format("http://MVCSite/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId={0}&code={1}",    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(appuser.Id), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code));
```

---

**Update**

For anyone trying to host multiple projects, you need one of these two things to be the same to still be able to use the confirmation code:

- Application Pool
- Machine Key

[Email Confirmation Error Invalid Token AspNet Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30615467/email-confirmation-error-invalid-token-aspnet-identity)

http://gunaatita.com/Blog/How-to-Generate-Machine-Key-using-IIS/1058